# Summary of all possible combinations of variables

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data frame which is individual-level data of people in a country. In the said data frame I have information on county or municipality of residence, sex, age, race and cancer status. I want to aggregate the data into a new data frame ordered by counties and stratified by age (in categories), sex and race. That is, create subgroups defined by a combination of these multiple variables. The original data has a structure similar to the fictitious data below.

```
    structure(list(Person_ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40), County_ID = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), Age = c(39, 
21, 65, 87, 19, 16, 48, 52, 31, 19, 24, 44, 38, 
39, 40, 27, 69, 71, 52, 53, 80, 23, 
21, 29, 38, 34, 39, 73, 54, 50, 52, 
43, 55, 57, 37, 24, 44, 37, 38, 
40), Sex = c("F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M"), Race = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2), `Cancer-status` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

with a structure like

| Person_ID | County_ID | Age | Sex | Race | Cancer_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 30 | M | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 41 | M | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 19 | F | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 37 | F | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 28 | F | 3 | 0 |
| 6 | 3 | 65 | M | 1 | 1 |

where Cancer_status is a dummy or binary variable and Race is a factor variable.

And I want a new data frame in the format below (similar to the data structure of **pennLC$data** in ***SpatialEpi package***). With the counts of cancer and population ordered by county and sorted by the 3 strata (race, sex and age). The new age variable is a factor or categorical variable.

| county | cancer | pop_county | race | Sex | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1492 | 1 | F | Under 40 |
| 1 | 0 | 365 | 1 | F | 40-59 |
| 1 | 1 | 68 | 1 | F | 60-69 |
| 1 | 0 | 73 | 1 | F | 70+ |
| 1 | 0 | 23351 | 2 | F | Under 40 |
| 1 | 5 | 12136 | 2 | F | 40-59 |

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want `dplyr`. Given your sample data, try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  mutate(Age = cut(Age, c(0, 40, 60, 70, Inf), right = FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(County_ID, Race, Sex, Age) %>%
  summarize(cancer = sum(`Cancer-status`), pop_county = n()) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 37 x 6
#    County_ID  Race Sex   Age      cancer pop_county
#        <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <fct>     <dbl>      <int>
#  1         1     1 F     [0,40)        0          1
#  2         1     1 F     [60,70)       0          1
#  3         1     2 F     [0,40)        0          1
#  4         1     2 M     [70,Inf)      0          1
#  5         1     3 M     [0,40)        0          1
#  6         2     1 M     [0,40)        1          1
#  7         2     1 M     [40,60)       0          1
#  8         2     2 F     [0,40)        1          2
#  9         2     3 F     [40,60)       0          1
# 10         2     3 M     [0,40)        0          1
# # ... with 27 more rows
```

You'll need to relabel the `Age` factor,

Comment: Thank you very much @r2evans

Comment: In addition to r2evans answer, I added %>%
  complete(County_ID, Race, Sex, Age) to get complete to show all possible combinations of the variables following the example here https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/07/tidyrcomplete-to-show-all-possible-combinations-of-variables/